# Vue - How to scope variables within template

Tags: vue.js

Can I scope data somehow within a component's template?

For example, if I have the following code:

```
data() {
    a: {test: 'Test A'},
    b: {test: 'Test B'}
}
```

Currently in the template I have to do

```
<div class="a">{{ a.test }}</div>
<div class="b">{{ b.test }}</div>
```

Is there any way I can scope data per element? For example, something like:

```
<div :scope="a">{{ test }}</div><!-- This prints 'Test A' -->
<div :scope="b">{{ test }}</div><!-- This prints 'Test B' -->
```

I do know that I can extract each item to a component, however, I was wondering if there is a way to do that within the same template? As it does not have own logic etc. so I don't want to extract it to a separate component just to scope the variable. However, it can get tedious repeating the same variable name many times.

For example, I have a form to create a new item, which has a number of inputs. I keep them under a variable (for example) `newItem`, which looks like

```
newItem: {
    input1: "",
    input2: "",
    input3: null,
    input4: false,
    // etc...
}
```

And in the template I would like to do

```
<div :scope="newItem">
    <input v-model="input1"/>
    <!-- etc.. --->
</div>
```

Instead of

```
<input v-model="newItem.input1"/>
<!--- etc... --->
```

Comment: A quick search through the documentation should tell you that this is not a feature of Vue. What is the practical use of this requirement? What is it you're trying to do and why?

Comment: I gave an example of what I'm trying to do. If I have a long variable name (possibly nested within other variables) and have 30 inputs, each using it multiple times (for label, input, errors etc.), then I have to repeat the same variable name 90+ times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO.

There's no such a way to do. And also `v-model` needs to be specified to the particular data else it will not work. Otherwise, we can think of [v-for](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-with-a-Component).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `v-for` with an inline array to create a "shortcut" of sorts to a lengthy variable and thus simplify code.  This also works with `v-model`.  For example:

```html
<div v-for="item of [obj1, obj2, obj3]">
  <label>{{item.label}}</label>
  <input type="text" v-model="item.value">
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el:'#app',
  data: {
    obj1:{label:'obj1 label', value:'val'},
    obj2:{label:'obj2 label', value:'val2'},
    obj3:{label:'obj3 label', value:'val3'}
  },
  computed: {
    output: function(){
      return JSON.stringify([this.obj1, this.obj2, this.obj3], null, 2);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h3>Editor</h3>
  <div v-for="item of [obj1, obj2, obj3]" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <label>{{item.label}}</label>
    <input type="text" v-model="item.value">
  </div>
  <h3>Output</h3>
  <pre v-html="output"></pre>
</div>
```

However, note that in the situation outlined by the OP it would likely be best to use a separate component.